# get UTC timestamp in python with datetime

Tags: python, datetime, timestamp, utc

Is there a way to get the UTC timestamp by specifying the date? What I would expect:

```
datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

should result in

```
 1199145600
```

Creating a naive datetime object means that there is no time zone information. If I look at the documentation for datetime.utcfromtimestamp, creating a UTC timestamp means leaving out the time zone information. So I would guess, that creating a naive datetime object (like I did) would result in a UTC timestamp. However:

```
then = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(float(then.strftime('%s')))
```

results in

```
2007-12-31 23:00:00
```

Is there still any hidden time zone information in the datetime object? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the issue is [`then.strftime('%s')` that expects local time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067218/get-utc-timestamp-in-python-with-datetime/13423091#comment18345335_13201504) but the timestamp indicates that `datetime(2008, 1, 1)` is in UTC.

Comment: Personally I find [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54936394/1804173) very helpful.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

**Naïve `datetime` versus aware `datetime`**

Default `datetime` objects are said to be "naïve": they keep time information without the time zone information. Think about naïve `datetime` as a relative number (ie: `+4`) without a clear origin (in fact your origin will be common throughout your system boundary).

In contrast, think about aware `datetime` as absolute numbers (ie: `8`) with a common origin for the whole world.

Without timezone information you **cannot** convert the "naive" datetime towards any non-naive time representation (where does `+4` targets if we don't know from where to start ?). This is why you can't have a `datetime.datetime.toutctimestamp()` method. (cf: http://bugs.python.org/issue1457227)

To check if your `datetime` `dt` is naïve, check `dt.tzinfo`, if `None`, then it's naïve:

```
datetime.now()        ## DANGER: returns naïve datetime pointing on local time
datetime(1970, 1, 1)  ## returns naïve datetime pointing on user given time
```

**I have naïve datetimes, what can I do ?**

You must make an assumption depending on your particular context:
The question you must ask yourself is: was your `datetime` on UTC ? or was it local time ?

- **If you were using UTC** (you are out of trouble):

  ```
  import calendar

  def dt2ts(dt):
      """Converts a datetime object to UTC timestamp

      naive datetime will be considered UTC.

      """

      return calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())
  ```
- **If you were NOT using UTC**, welcome to hell.

  You have to make your `datetime` non-naïve prior to using the former
  function, by giving them back their intended timezone.

  You'll need **the name of the timezone** and **the information about
  if DST was in effect** when producing the target naïve datetime (the
  last info about DST is required for cornercases):

  ```
  import pytz     ## pip install pytz

  mytz = pytz.timezone('Europe/Amsterdam')             ## Set your timezone

  dt = mytz.normalize(mytz.localize(dt, is_dst=True))  ## Set is_dst accordingly
  ```

  **Consequences of not providing `is_dst`**:

  Not using `is_dst` will generate incorrect time (and UTC timestamp)
  if target datetime was produced while a backward DST was put in place
  (for instance changing DST time by removing one hour).

  Providing incorrect `is_dst` will of course generate incorrect
  time (and UTC timestamp) only on DST overlap or holes. And, when 
  providing 
  also incorrect time, occuring in "holes" (time that never existed due
  to forward shifting DST), `is_dst` will give an interpretation of 
  how to consider this bogus time, and this is the only case where 
  `.normalize(..)` will actually do something here, as it'll then 
  translate it as an actual valid time (changing the datetime AND the 
  DST object if required). Note that `.normalize()` is not required 
  for having a correct UTC timestamp at the end, but is probably 
  recommended if you dislike the idea of having bogus times in your 
  variables, especially if you re-use this variable elsewhere.

  and **AVOID USING THE FOLLOWING**: (cf: [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279))

  ```
  dt = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone('Europe/Amsterdam'))  ## BAD !!
  ```

  Why? because `.replace()` replaces blindly the `tzinfo` without 
  taking into account the target time and will choose a bad DST object. 
  Whereas `.localize()` uses the target time and your `is_dst` hint
  to select the right DST object.

**OLD incorrect answer** (thanks @J.F.Sebastien for bringing this up):

Hopefully, it is quite easy to guess the timezone (your local origin) when you create your naive `datetime` object as it is related to the system configuration that you would hopefully NOT change between the naive datetime object creation and the moment when you want to get the UTC timestamp. This trick can be used to give an **imperfect** question.

By using `time.mktime` we can create an `utc_mktime`:

```
def utc_mktime(utc_tuple):
    """Returns number of seconds elapsed since epoch

    Note that no timezone are taken into consideration.

    utc tuple must be: (year, month, day, hour, minute, second)

    """

    if len(utc_tuple) == 6:
        utc_tuple += (0, 0, 0)
    return time.mktime(utc_tuple) - time.mktime((1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))

def datetime_to_timestamp(dt):
    """Converts a datetime object to UTC timestamp"""

    return int(utc_mktime(dt.timetuple()))
```

You must make sure that your `datetime` object is created on the same timezone than the one that has created your `datetime`.

*This last solution is incorrect because it makes the assumption that the UTC offset from now is the same than the UTC offset from EPOCH.* Which is not the case for a lot of timezones (in specific moment of the year for the Daylight Saving Time (DST) offsets).

Comment: Naive datetime object should always represent time in UTC. Other timezones should be used only for I/O (display). There is `datetime.timestamp()` method in Python 3.3.

Comment: `time.mktime()` should be used only for local time. `calendar.timegm()` could be used to convert utc time tuple to posix timestamp. Or better yet use only datetime methods. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423091/4279)

Comment: -1. Your code assumes that utc_offset(now) and utc_offset(epoch) are the same in the local timezone. It is not so in 116 timezones (from 430 common timezones).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thanks for bringing that up. I've notified that this solution is incorrect, and proposed an alternative solution.

Comment: still -1: do not use `.replace()` with a timezone that has a non-fixed utc offset such as `'Europe/Amsterdam'`. See [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Oh my ! You are right ! I've corrected my answer to use ``.localize()``. Many thanks for your invaluable feedbacks. And I'm hoping that this question gets finally an acceptable and correct answer with this edit.

Comment: 1- Do you understand why you should not use `.replace(tzinfo=get_localzone())`? 2- `timegm()` returns `int` already. No need to wrap it with `int`. Also, `.timetuple()` drops fractions of a second.

Comment: I've added lengthy explanation of why you should not use ``.replace(..)`` (removed the ``.replace`` occurence which slipped through). I removed the system localzone usage BTW as it was probably out of topic. I removed the usage of ``int`` which had no reason to be kept here. I added some information on consequences when not providing ``is_dst`` on ``.localize()``. Thanks for your careful reviews.

Comment: 1- `datetime` does have `.timestamp()` method in Python 3 (it interprets the naive datetime as the time in the local timezone -- it breaks if C `mktime()` does not have access to a historical timezone database that is why `tzlocal.get_localzone()` can be useful: to provide access to the tz database in a portable manner). 2- The part that converts timezone-aware datetime to "seconds since epoch" is missing in the answer.

Comment: ```import calendar
calendar.timegm(dt.utctimetuple())``` 

gives me:

```AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'utc_timetuple'
```

Comment: @NikolayShindarov You may want to re-read carefully your comment (hint: there is a rogue underscore in the error message). Might that explain your issue ?

Comment: NameError: name 'dt' is not defined For the `dt = mytz.normalize(mytz.localize(dt, is_dst=True))` line

Answer (score 38):

Another possibility is:

```
d = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
epoch = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)
t = (d - epoch).total_seconds()
```

This works as both "d" and "epoch" are naive datetimes, making the "-" operator valid, and returning an interval. `total_seconds()` turns the interval into seconds. Note that `total_seconds()` returns a float, even `d.microsecond == 0`

Comment: Well not really, the idea is the same but this one is easier to understand :)

Comment: You'd think there would be a single method in the time library or something...sheesh

Comment: To get the timestamp, do datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()

Comment: @Eugene `datetime.datetime.utcnow().timestamp()` gives different result than this solution

Comment: @alper, yes, it just gives you a current time timestamp

Answer (score 24):

A simple solution without using external modules:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
int(dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp())
```

Comment: Tnx! This is best answer!

Answer (score 21):

Also note the [calendar.timegm()](http://docs.python.org/library/calendar.html#calendar.timegm) function as described by [this](http://ruslanspivak.com/2011/07/20/how-to-convert-python-utc-datetime-object-to-unix-timestamp/) blog entry:

```
import calendar
calendar.timegm(utc_timetuple)
```

The output should agree with the solution of vaab.

Answer (score 16):

If input datetime object is in UTC:

```
>>> dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
1199145600.0
```

Note: it returns float i.e., microseconds are represented as fractions of a second.

If input date object is in UTC:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> utc_date = date(2008, 1, 1)
>>> timestamp = (utc_date.toordinal() - date(1970, 1, 1).toordinal()) * 24*60*60
1199145600
```

See more details at [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Answer (score 9):

I feel like the main answer is still not so clear, and it's worth taking the time to understand ***time*** and ***timezones***.

The most important thing to understand when dealing with time is that time is ***relative***!

- `2017-08-30 13:23:00`: (a naive datetime), represents a ***local*** time somewhere in the world, but note that `2017-08-30 13:23:00` in London is **NOT THE SAME TIME** as `2017-08-30 13:23:00` in San Francisco.

Because the same time string can be interpreted as different points-in-time depending on where you are in the world, there is a need for an *absolute* notion of time.

A **UTC timestamp** is a number in seconds (or milliseconds) *from* Epoch (defined as `1 January 1970 00:00:00` at `GMT` timezone +00:00 offset).

Epoch is anchored on the GMT timezone and therefore is an absolute point in time. A **UTC timestamp** being an *offset* from an absolute time therefore defines **an absolute point in time**.

***This makes it possible to order events in time.***

Without timezone information, time is relative, and cannot be converted to an **absolute** notion of time without providing some indication of what timezone the naive datetime should be anchored to.

**What are the types of time used in computer system?**

- **naive datetime**: usually for display, in local time (i.e. in the browser) where the OS can provide timezone information to the program.
- **UTC timestamps**: A UTC timestamp is an absolute point in time, as mentioned above, but it is anchored in a given timezone, so a UTC timestamp can be converted to a datetime in **any** timezone, however it does not *contain* timezone information. What does that mean? That means that 1504119325 corresponds to `2017-08-30T18:55:24Z`, or `2017-08-30T17:55:24-0100` or also `2017-08-30T10:55:24-0800`. It doesn't tell you **where** the datetime recorded is from. It's usually used on the server side to record events (logs, etc...) or used to convert a ***timezone aware datetime*** to an ***absolute point in time*** and compute **time differences**.
- **ISO-8601 datetime** string: The ISO-8601 is a standardized format to record datetime with timezone. (It's in fact several formats, read on here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) It is used to communicate timezone aware datetime information in a serializable manner between systems.

**When to use which? or rather when do you need to care about timezones?**

- If you need in any way to care about **time-of-day**, you need timezone information. A calendar or alarm needs time-of-day to set a meeting at the correct time of the day for any user in the world. If this data is saved on a server, the server needs to know what timezone the datetime corresponds to.
- To compute time differences between events coming from different places in the world, UTC timestamp is enough, but you lose the ability to analyze at what time of day events occured (ie. for web analytics, you may want to know when users come to your site **in their local time**: do you see more users in the morning or the evening? You can't figure that out without time of day information.

**Timezone offset in a date string**:

Another point that is important, is that timezone offset in a date string is **not fixed**. That means that because `2017-08-30T10:55:24-0800` says the offset `-0800` or 8 hours back, doesn't mean that it will always be!

In the summer it may well be in daylight saving time, and it would be `-0700`

What that means is that **timezone offset (+0100)** is not the same as **timezone name (Europe/France)** or even **timezone designation (CET)**

`America/Los_Angeles` timezone is a ***place in the world***, but it turns into `PST` (Pacific Standard Time) timezone offset notation in the winter, and `PDT` (Pacific Daylight Time) in the summer.

So, on top of getting the timezone offset from the datestring, you should also get the timezone name to be accurate.

Most packages will be able to convert numeric offsets from daylight saving time to standard time on their own, but that is not necessarily trivial with just offset. For example `WAT` timezone designation in West Africa, is UTC+0100 just like `CET` timezone in France, but France observes daylight saving time, while West Africa does not (because they're close to the equator)

So, in short, it's complicated. VERY complicated, and that's why you should not do this yourself, but trust a package that does it for you, and KEEP IT UP TO DATE!

Comment: see my blog post about date and time in Python to understand the pitfalls of the different packages
https://medium.com/@eleroy/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-date-and-time-in-python-with-datetime-pytz-dateutil-timedelta-309bfbafb3f7

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a problem with using utcfromtimestamp and specifying time zones. A nice example/explanation is available on the following question:

[How to specify time zone (UTC) when converting to Unix time? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077285/how-to-specify-time-zone-utc-when-converting-to-unix-time-python)

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer seems not work for me. My solution:

```
import time
utc_0 = int(time.mktime(datetime(1970, 01, 01).timetuple()))
def datetime2ts(dt):
    """Converts a datetime object to UTC timestamp"""
    return int(time.mktime(dt.utctimetuple())) - utc_0
```

Comment: it fails if the current (`dt`) UTC offset of the local timezone and in 1970 differ. `mktime()` expects local time.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> dt.strftime("%s")
'1199163600'
```

Edit: @Daniel is correct, this would convert it to the machine's timezone. Here is a revised answer:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc)
>>> dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, timezone.utc)
>>> int((dt-epoch).total_seconds())
'1199145600'
```

In fact, its not even necessary to specify `timezone.utc`, because the time difference is the same so long as both `datetime` have the same timezone (or no timezone).

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> dt = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> int((dt-epoch).total_seconds())
1199145600
```

Comment: this method doesn't return utc, but rather adjusts the datetime to current timezone. ie. if now is 12am in tz +3, it will return 9am in epoch.

Comment: Ah you are right. My timezone was UTC - which is why it worked.

Comment: If you are going to use the (Python 3.2 and newer) `timezone.utc` object, then just use that with `.timestamp()`: `datetime(2008, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()`. No need to create an epoch object and subtract..

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to phrase your question is
`Is there a way to get the timestamp by specifying the date in UTC?`, because timestamp is just a number which is absolute, not relative. The relative (or timezone aware) piece is the date.

I find pandas very convenient for timestamps, so:

```
import pandas as pd
dt1 = datetime(2008, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
ts1 = pd.Timestamp(dt1, tz='utc').timestamp()
# make sure you get back dt1
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts1)
```

Comment: Using pandas is IMHO the right approach, for current time there is also t = Timestamp.utcnow() to directly get the right time :)

Comment: This is neat, but for clarity of readers can I explicitly specifying the datetime import as a copy/paste of this snippet fails. So add `import datetime as dt` and then called using `dt.datetime`.

Comment: Also quite annoying that `.timestamp()` returns POSIX timestamp as float not an int.

Comment: Recommending pandas for only a timestamp feels overkill.