# Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, timezone, pytz

This is just another post on `pytz`.

There are two functions to convert datetime objects between two timezones. The second functions works for all cases. The first function fails in two cases, (3) and (4). Similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1379740/pytz-localize-vs-datetime-replace) did not have an issue like this. Any explanation based on the difference between `localize(datetime.datetime)` and `replace(tzinfo)` would be a great help.

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> import pytz
```

## First function (buggy)

The function below uses `datetime.datetime.replace(tzinfo)`.

```
def buggy_timezone_converter(input_dt, current_tz='UTC', target_tz='US/Eastern'):
    '''input_dt is a datetime.datetime object'''
    current_tz = pytz.timezone(current_tz)
    target_tz = pytz.timezone(target_tz)
    target_dt = input_dt.replace(tzinfo=current_tz).astimezone(target_tz)
    return target_tz.normalize(target_dt)
```

Notice the four datetime conversion now.

(1) from UTC to EST -- OK

```
>>> buggy_timezone_converter(parse('2013-02-26T04:00:00'))
Out[608]: datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 25, 23, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
```

(2) from UTC to EDT -- OK

```
>>> buggy_timezone_converter(parse('2013-05-26T04:00:00'))
Out[609]: datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

(3) from EST to UTC -- Not OK. Time offset is 4 hours 56 minutes. It is supposed to be 5 hours

```
>>> buggy_timezone_converter(parse('2013-02-26T04:00:00'), target_tz='UTC', current_tz='US/Eastern')
Out[610]: datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 8, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

(4) from EDT to UTC -- Not OK. Time offset is 4 hours 56 minutes. It is supposed to be 4 hours. Daylight saving is not considered.

```
>>> buggy_timezone_converter(parse('2013-05-26T04:00:00'), current_tz='US/Eastern', target_tz='UTC')
Out[611]: datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26, 8, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

## Second function (Works perfectly)

The function below uses `pytz.timezone.localize(datetime.datetime)`. It works perfectly

```
def good_timezone_converter(input_dt, current_tz='UTC', target_tz='US/Eastern'):
    current_tz = pytz.timezone(current_tz)
    target_tz = pytz.timezone(target_tz)
    target_dt = current_tz.localize(input_dt).astimezone(target_tz)
    return target_tz.normalize(target_dt)
```

(1) from UTC to EST -- OK

```
>>> good_timezone_converter(parse('2013-02-26T04:00:00'))
Out[618]: datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 25, 23, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EST-1 day, 19:00:00 STD>)
```

(2) from UTC to EDT -- OK

```
>>> good_timezone_converter(parse('2013-05-26T04:00:00'))
Out[619]: datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' EDT-1 day, 20:00:00 DST>)
```

(3) from EST to UTC -- OK.

```
>>> good_timezone_converter(parse('2013-02-26T04:00:00'), current_tz='US/Eastern', target_tz='UTC')
Out[621]: datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 9, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

(4) from EDT to UTC -- OK.

```
>>> good_timezone_converter(parse('2013-05-26T04:00:00'), current_tz='US/Eastern', target_tz='UTC')
Out[620]: datetime.datetime(2013, 5, 26, 8, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce: `>>> timezone_converter(datetime.datetime(2013,02,26,4,0,0,0), target_tz='UTC', current_tz='US/Eastern')`
`datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 9, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the import lines
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> import pytz

Comment: Either your question is a duplicate of [pytz localize vs datetime replace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1379740/4279) or you should ask a more specific question ([update the current question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27531718/edit)) if you are not satisfied with the existing answers. Please, use different names for the first and the second function e.g., `convert_tz_replace()` and `convert_tz()`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: check again (update `pytz`). `timezone_converter_replace(datetime(2013,2,26,4,0,0,0), target_tz='UTC', current_tz='US/Eastern')` ->
`datetime.datetime(2013, 2, 26, 8, 56, tzinfo=<UTC>)` i.e., `.replace()` fails as documented.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian that was a direct copy/paste from my test. I don't know why I got different results, but I did. Maybe that's a clue of some kind.

Comment: See also https://www.reddit.com/r/CodingHelp/comments/10638wm/pst_adjustment_goes_to_0753_why_is_my_timezone/ for a possible explanation

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I assume you have these questions:

- why does the first function work for UTC timezone?
- why does it fail for `'US/Eastern'` timezone (`DstTzInfo` instance)?
- why does the second function work for all provided examples?

The first function is incorrect because it uses `d.replace(tzinfo=dsttzinfo_instance)` instead of `dsttzinfo_instance.localize(d)` .

The second function is correct most of the time except during ambiguous or non-existing times e.g., during DST transitions -- you can change the behaviour by passing `is_dst` parameter to `.localize()`: `False`(default)/`True`/`None`(raise an exception).

The first function works for UTC timezone because it has a fixed utc offset (zero) for any date. Other timezones such as `America/New_York` may have different utc offsets at different times (Daylight saving time, war time, any time that some local politician might think is a good idea -- it can be *anything* -- the tz database works in most cases). To implement `tzinfo.utcoffset(dt)`, `tzinfo.tzname(dt)`, `tzinfo.dst(dt)` methods `pytz` uses a collection of `DstTzInfo` instances each with a different set of `(_tzname, _utcoffset, _dst)` attributes. Given `dt` (date/time) **and `is_dst`**, `.localize()` method chooses an appropriate (in most cases but *not always*) `DstTzInfo` instance from the collection. `pytz.timezone('America/New_York')` returns a `DstTzInfo` instance with `(_tzname, _utcoffset, _dst)` attributes that correspond to some *undocumented* moment in time (different `pytz` versions may return different values -- the current version may return `tzinfo` instance that corresponds to the earliest date for which zoneinfo is available -- you don't want this value most of the time: I think the motivation behind the choice of the default value is to highlight the error (passing `pytz.timezone` to `datetime` constructor or `.replace()` method).

To summarize: `.localize()` selects appropriate utcoffset, tzname, dst values, `.replace()` uses the default (inappropriate) value. UTC has only one set of utcoffset, tzname, dst therefore the default value may be used and `.replace()` method works with UTC timezone. You need to pass a datetime object and `is_dst` parameter to select appropriate values for other timezones such as `'America/New_York'`.

In principle, `pytz` could have called `localize()` method to implement `utcoffset()`, `tzname()`, `dst()` methods even if `dt.tzinfo == self`: it would make these methods O(log n) in time where `n` is number of intervals with different (utcoffset, tzname, dst) values but `datetime` constructor and `.replace()` would work as is i.e., the explicit `localize()` call would be necessary only to pass `is_dst`.