# Baffling timezone Behavior

Tags: python, timezone, pytz

```
import datetime
import pytz # install from pip

US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")

dt = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE)
print(dt == dt.replace(tzinfo=US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE)) # True

dt = datetime.datetime.now(tz=US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE)
print(dt == dt.replace(tzinfo=US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE)) # False
```

So it looks like `datetime.datetime.now(tz=..)` isn't set to the timezone I specify...

It looks like the timezone is set when using `datetime.now`, but it's off by an hour-zone.

Why is this?

Comment: Use `localize`, not `replace`.  Read [the pytz docs](http://pythonhosted.org/pytz).

Comment: @MattJohnson: `.now(tz)` works as is. You shouldn't use `tz.localize(.now())` here  even if the local timezone is `'US/Pacific'` (the latter fails during end-of-DST transitions while the former works without an issue even for ambiguous local times).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian - Yes, agreed for the case of "now".  I was speaking in general. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only correct formula in your question is:

```
dt = datetime.now(US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE)
```

`US_PACIFIC_TIMEZONE` may have different utc offsets at different dates e.g., due to DST transitions. You shouldn't use `.replace()` method (or `tzinfo` constructor parameter) with such `pytz` timezones. Here's an [explanation on why you should not use `replace()` with `pytz` timezones that have a variable utc offset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27592919/4279).