# Python: Converting from one time zone to another yields weird non-whole number hour difference

Tags: python, datetime, pytz, python-dateutil, tzinfo

I'm simply trying to take a naïve time, give it a local time zone, and then convert it into UTC.

I'm using the following code:

```
        create_time_local = parser.parse(timestring).replace(tzinfo=timezone('America/Chicago'))
        create_time_utc = create_time_local.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))

print('+++++++++' + timestring + '++++++++')
        print('*****************' + create_time_local.strftime(fmt) + '***************')
        print('-----' + create_time_utc.strftime(fmt) + '-----')
```

I can't figure out why, but here's the output:

> +++++++++09/20/15 2:00:00 AM++++++++
>
> *****************09/20/15 02:00:00 AM***************
>   -----09/20/15 07:51:00 AM-----

The correct answer, of course, should be 7:00 AM.  I can't figure out why it's coming out 7:51 AM.

---

Alternate working code besides the linked code in the duplicate:

```
        create_time_local_naive = parser.parse(timestring)
        local_tz = timezone('America/Chicago')
        create_time_local = local_tz.localize(create_time_local_naive)
        create_time_utc = create_time_local.astimezone(timezone('UTC'))
```

Comment: can you print timestring too?

Comment: @FoobieBletch It looks similar, but I don't think it's a duplicate because the answer is to create a naïve time zone, add the time zone, and then do the conversion, which is what I'm doing.

Comment: Try using `pytz.utc.normallize()` to convert to utc instead of `.astimezone()` .

Comment: Well, I stand corrected, thanks

Comment: don't call `.replace(tzinfo=pytz_timezone)`; it may fail for any timezone with a non-fixed utc offset (many of them), use `pytz_timezone.localize(naive, is_dst=None)` instead. Related: [Datetime Timezone conversion using pytz](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27531718/4279)