# Weird issue with pytz tzname

Tags: python, pytz

I was working with some timezone code when I noticed this ambiguity. When trying to get the tzname for Asia/Singapore, I get the UTC Offset. If I do the same with Asia/Kolkata, I get the correct timezone name - IST.

```
pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore').tzname(datetime.now())
'+08'
```

```
pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata').tzname(datetime.now())
'IST'
```

Is there a reason for this ambiguity and is there a workaround that will give me the actual timezone code i.e. SGT?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use abbreviated timezone name(PST, IST) in Pytz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109945/how-to-use-abbreviated-timezone-namepst-ist-in-pytz)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think pytz have 'SGT' in the timezone abbreviation list. I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
common_name = pytz.timezone('Asia/Singapore')
abbr = common_name.localize(dt.now(), is_dst=None)
print(abbr.tzname())
```

And it give me the output `+08`. Bu for other zones like:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
common_name = pytz.timezone("US/Pacific")
abbr = common_name.localize(dt.now(), is_dst=None)
print(abbr.tzname())
```

it gives me `PDT`. And I tried several other timezones and seems like they don't include **SGT** in their list. Maybe they will have it in future versions, but right now they just don't have it.