# How to conver datetime to timestamp epoch

Tags: python, python-2.7, timestamp

i am new to python 2.7, wondering and facing issue how to convert datetime to timestamp epoch.

Also the date time is in current UTC.
example :
2016-05-11 18:33:44  to 1462958071

Comment: @EdChum yes, flagging as such.

Comment: the example in the question is incorrect: `str(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1462958071)) == '2016-05-11 09:14:31'`, not `2016-05-11 18:33:44` i.e., the utc time (`2016-05-11 18:33:44`) does not correspond to "timestamp epoch" (`1462958071`). The corresponding POSIX timestamp is `1462991624`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Convert string to python datetime object and then parse the seconds

```
a ="2016-05-11 18:33:44"
b= datetime.strptime(a,"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
print b.strftime('%s') # returns time in epoch
```

Comment: Awesome ,its working...!

Comment: @VinothMohan: the answer is *wrong* unless your local timezone is utc and you are on a platform that supports `%s` (*nix). There is no need for that: [there is a portable solution to convert a datetime that represents UTC time to "timestamp epoch"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13423091/4279)