# Converting python datetime to timestamp and back in UTC still uses local timezone

Tags: python, datetime, time, pytz

I'm working with a code that gives me utc timestamps and I want to convert them to appropriate datetimes.   Unfortunately when I test simple cases with pytz the datetime has an added 6 hours (the CST offset to UTC).  I need to keep timezone data correct because I am calculating difference between other timezones as well.  Any ideas why and how to convert a utc timestamp to a utc datetime?

```
In [1]: import pytz

In [2]: from datetime import datetime

In [3]: import time

In [4]: datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(datetime(7,1,1, tzinfo=pytz.UTC).timetuple()), tz=pytz.UTC)
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 1, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [5]: datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(datetime(7,1,1).utctimetuple()), tz=pytz.UTC)
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 1, 6, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)

In [6]: datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(datetime(7,1,1).utctimetuple()))
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2007, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: related: [How can I get a date converted to seconds since epoch according to UTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hmm I found the answer here: [How to specify time zone (UTC) when converting to Unix time? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077285/how-to-specify-time-zone-utc-when-converting-to-unix-time-python)

```
In [101]: ts = calendar.timegm(datetime(2010, 7, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc).timetuple())

In [102]: datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz=pytz.utc)
Out[102]: datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Answer (score 171):

To get a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC from "seconds since the epoch" timestamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts)
```

If you want to get an aware datetime object for UTC timezone:

```
import pytz

aware_utc_dt = utc_dt.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

To convert it to some other timezone:

```
tz = pytz.timezone('America/Montreal')
dt = aware_utc_dt.astimezone(tz)
```

To convert the timestamp to an aware datetime object in the given timezone directly:

```
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, tz)
```

Comment: what is  the variable `ts`?

Comment: @Curious the method has words: "from timestamp" in its name. It suggests that the argument is a timestamp.  The text description before the code hints at it too. Writing it as 'utc_dt = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp)` I thought would be excessive so I've abbreviated `timestamp` to `ts`.

Comment: `ts` is of type integer, providing 0 results in UTC time `1970-01-01 00:00:00`, i.e. a Unix Timestamp.

Comment: @Siete I didn't get what you are trying to say but `ts` can be float

Comment: @jfs, you're absolutely right, don't know what hit me :D What I was trying to say was towards "IssamLaradji", I interpreted his question as "what does ts hold as a value". What I meant to say was "it's numerical". In retrospect, seeing his experience, this was probably needless to explain.