# Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python

Tags: python, datetime, utc

I am dealing with dates in Python and I need to convert them to UTC timestamps to be used
inside Javascript. The following code does not work:

```
>>> d = datetime.date(2011,01,01)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(time.mktime(d.timetuple()))
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31, 23, 0)
```

Converting the date object first to datetime also does not help. I tried the example at this [link](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/hkw9u/create_utc_timestamp_for_given_date) from, but:

```
from pytz import utc, timezone
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
input_date = datetime(year=2011, month=1, day=15)
```

and now either:

```
mktime(utc.localize(input_date).utctimetuple())
```

or

```
mktime(timezone('US/Eastern').localize(input_date).utctimetuple())
```

does work.

So general question: how can I get a date converted to seconds since epoch according to UTC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I convert local time to UTC in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79797/how-do-i-convert-local-time-to-utc-in-python)

Comment: I'm not sure I would agree with marking it as a duplicate. While the solutions are similar the questions are not. One (this one) is attempting to create a timestamp from a `datetime.date`, the other is attempting to convert a string representation from one timezone to another. As someone looking for a solution to this problem, I may not conclude that the latter will provide the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: datetime(date.year,date.month,date.day).timestamp()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python, how do you convert a \`datetime\` object to seconds?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852855/in-python-how-do-you-convert-a-datetime-object-to-seconds)

Comment: Beware: mktime is up to 10x slower than other approaches. Since it's not unlikely you're doing this in a hot path, it matters.

Answer (score 547):

If `d = date(2011, 1, 1)` is in UTC:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, date
>>> import calendar
>>> timestamp1 = calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())
>>> datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp1)
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

If `d` is in local timezone:

```
>>> import time
>>> timestamp2 = time.mktime(d.timetuple()) # DO NOT USE IT WITH UTC DATE
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp2)
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

`timestamp1` and `timestamp2` may differ if midnight in the local timezone is not the same time instance as midnight in UTC.

`mktime()` may return a wrong result if `d` corresponds to an [ambiguous local time (e.g., during DST transition)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12165691/python-datetime-with-timezone-to-epoch/12166400#comment39565270_12166400) or if `d` is a past(future) date when the utc offset might have been different *and* the C `mktime()` has no access to [the tz database](http://www.iana.org/time-zones/repository/tz-link.html) on the given platform. You could [use `pytz` module (e.g., via `tzlocal.get_localzone()`) to get access to the tz database on all platforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365806/4279). Also, [`utcfromtimestamp()` may fail and `mktime()` may return non-POSIX timestamp if `"right"` timezone is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28949623/python-datetime-and-utc-offset-conversion-ignoring-timezone-daylight-savings/28950133#comment46155743_28950133).

---

To convert `datetime.date` object that represents date in UTC without `calendar.timegm()`:

```
DAY = 24*60*60 # POSIX day in seconds (exact value)
timestamp = (utc_date.toordinal() - date(1970, 1, 1).toordinal()) * DAY
timestamp = (utc_date - date(1970, 1, 1)).days * DAY
```

### How can I get a date converted to seconds since epoch according to UTC?

To convert `datetime.datetime` (not `datetime.date`) object that already represents time in UTC to the corresponding POSIX timestamp (a `float`).

#### Python 3.3+

[`datetime.timestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
from datetime import timezone

timestamp = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()
```

Note: It is necessary to supply `timezone.utc` explicitly otherwise `.timestamp()` assume that your naive datetime object is in local timezone.

#### Python 3 (< 3.3)

From the docs for [`datetime.utcfromtimestamp()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/datetime#datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp):

> There is no method to obtain the timestamp from a datetime instance,
>   but POSIX timestamp corresponding to a datetime instance dt can be
>   easily calculated as follows. For a naive dt:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

> And for an aware dt:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)) / timedelta(seconds=1)
```

Interesting read: [Epoch time vs. time of day](http://www.ucolick.org/~sla/leapsecs/epochtime.html) on the difference between *What time is it?* and *How many seconds have elapsed?*

See also: [datetime needs an "epoch" method](http://bugs.python.org/issue2736)

#### Python 2

To adapt the above code for Python 2:

```
timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

where [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) is equivalent to `(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6` computed with true division enabled.

#### [Example](http://ideone.com/rvH9u)

```
from __future__ import division
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def totimestamp(dt, epoch=datetime(1970,1,1)):
    td = dt - epoch
    # return td.total_seconds()
    return (td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 86400) * 10**6) / 10**6 

now = datetime.utcnow()
print now
print totimestamp(now)
```

Beware of [floating-point issues](http://bugs.python.org/issue8644).

#### Output

```
2012-01-08 15:34:10.022403
1326036850.02
```

### How to convert an aware `datetime` object to POSIX timestamp

```
assert dt.tzinfo is not None and dt.utcoffset() is not None
timestamp = dt.timestamp() # Python 3.3+
```

On Python 3:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone

epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
timestamp = (dt - epoch) / timedelta(seconds=1)
integer_timestamp = (dt - epoch) // timedelta(seconds=1)
```

On Python 2:

```
# utc time = local time              - utc offset
utc_naive  = dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - dt.utcoffset()
timestamp = (utc_naive - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: For the Python 2 case, why not: `timestamp = (dt - datetime.fromtimestamp(0)).total_seconds()` ?

Comment: @m01: `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` is more explicit. `fromtimestamp()` is incorrect here (`dt` is in UTC so `utcfromtimestamp()` should be used instead).

Comment: why does it return a floating point number? what if the script only accept an integer?

Comment: @ribot: to return the timestamp as a single number with precision that could be better than one second (notice `microseconds` above). Depending on your application you could return the timestamp measured in microsecond to get an integer or just round the float result.

Comment: when using Python 2.7.2. it compains TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'datetime.timedelta' and 'datetime.timedelta'

Comment: @LymanZerga: the code between `Python < 3.3` and `Python 2` headers is for Python 3. `/` is not defined for `timedelta` in Python 2.

Comment: @dannysauer wrong. Read [the corresponding Python issue that is linked in the answer.](http://bugs.python.org/issue8644)

Comment: Note `total_seconds()` was introduced in Python 2.7. Is there any approach for <2.7?

Comment: @fedorqui look at `totimestamp()` function in the answer.

Comment: as much as I love python, its date-time lib is seriously broken.

Comment: @Realfun: timezones, DST transitions, the tz database, leap seconds exist independent of Python.

Comment: Sorry to bother but is there a reason why `(dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=dt.tzinfo)).total_seconds()` would not work?

Comment: @qff yes. There are multiple reasons why it may fail for various dt.

Comment: @Scott: [timezone.utc exists](http://ideone.com/gDbUlN). Don't make such changes without a comment.

Comment: On 3.5.2 I get "AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'utc' ", with regard to timezone.utc.  I'll take your word that it works on 3.3.  Roger regarding change w/o comment.  My apologies.

Comment: Now that I look at your link it makes sense.  I was using `pytz.timezone()`.  It might help if you specify that you are using `datetime.timezone`.

Comment: Just use [`arrow`](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) , it is a good tip by [Mathieu Longtin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896913/1115187) (an alternative answer)

Comment: @maxkoryukov I don't see how `datetime(2011, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()` is worse than `arrow.get(2011, 1, 1).timestamp` answer (btw, you might have seen my comment from 2016 there). You don't need 3rd party modules to work with the utc timezone. In general, I prefer [`pendulum`](https://pendulum.eustace.io) if I need simple consistent datetime API  and predictable results. See [Why not Arrow?](https://github.com/sdispater/pendulum#why-not-arrow)

Comment: @jfs , thanks for `pendulum` - it is a good shot, I will try to use. About `datetime(2011, 1, 1, tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()` - python2 can't play with `timestamp()` - it is not implemented there... 

https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime


But your answer **is very good**, comprehensive and educational. I like such answers on SO

Comment: @maxkoryukov: the answer provides solutions for legacy python versions too.

Comment: @jfs , thanks again, it is the informative article. But I don't want to bother with all these rules, legacy stuff, Python's quirks. I just need a working solution. With **`arrow`** I need just install and write one line — and this line will work for all versions of Python (I required for me). So, between *[read the article and write your own awesome solution without deps]* and *[use arrow]* I prefer the last one;) Probably, it is very close to NodeJS/NPM approach.

Comment: @maxkoryukov: you don't need to write anything. *Working* solutions are already in the answer. If you don't want to read the full answer, choose the first solution you see: `calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())`  (it works for all versions of Python).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153513/discussion-between-maxkoryukov-and-jfs).

Comment: I don't get why the time libs deal with timezones at all. Best to do everything in UTC and convert to/from a user's timezone only on the frontend!

Comment: This article has a great explanation of why you should make your datetime instances offset aware: https://howchoo.com/g/ywi5m2vkodk/working-with-datetime-objects-and-timezones-in-python

Comment: @Scott ugh at 3rd party modules

Comment: **Potential bug**: For me (local timezone CET) the calculation in Python 2.7.15rc1 was off by one hour. Once I replaced `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` by `datetime.fromtimestamp(0)` it was working.

Comment: @Murphy please, understand that UTC != CET (dt must be in UTC in the formula) and therefore fromtimestamp(0) is wrong. It might work by accident (if you pass local time as dt (again, local time may differ from UTC) and if it happens that the utc offset for your local timezone is the same as it was on Jun 1 1970 (obviously, it may be different)). See earliest comments above.

Comment: Perhaps I should've been more detailed here. The `datetime` object I'm comparing with has also been created using `datetime.fromtimestamp()`, and though this as well as `datetime(1970, 1, 1)` were reported as naive objects they showed that offset. I've got no idea why it is that way, but the workaround should be transparent regarding the local timezone and thus valid for any TZ setting.

Comment: @Murphy do not subtract naive datetime objects that represent time in different time zones. It is like subtracting miles from kilometers — the result is non-sense.

Comment: Why do you need that play around time zones in Py3? `datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 4, 21, 34, 359000, tzinfo=tzutc())` and `datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 18, 4, 21, 34, 359000, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 7200))` correctly works with `.timestamp()`. Did I miss the point?

Comment: @0andriy: Do you mean `dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc).timestamp()` code? the input in the answer (`dt`) is a naive datetime object that represents time in UTC (the following NOTE in the answer should have made it clear)

Comment: where's dt defined?

Comment: @baxx: `d` is `datetime.date` instance (the input from the question). `dt` is the corresponding `datetime.datetime` instance.

Comment: @jfs Would `dt.astimezone()` work instead of `utc_naive  = dt.replace(tzinfo=None) - dt.utcoffset()`? I think I am missing something important here. I get that with `dt.replace` above, the resultant datetime obj is not timezone aware, while it is in case of `astimezone`, but I don't understand why that is a problem. (This is for python 2.7 specifically, python3 is a lot cleaner now)

Comment: @0xc0de `dt.astimezone()` is a type error on Python 2.

Answer (score 115):

For **unix systems only**:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> d = datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
>>> d.strftime("%s")  # <-- THIS IS THE CODE YOU WANT
'1293832800'
```

*Note 1:* dizzyf observed that this **applies localized timezones**. Don't use in production.

*Note 2:* Jakub Narębski noted that this **ignores timezone information** even for offset-aware datetime (tested for Python 2.7).

Comment: A good answer if you know what system your code will run under, but it's important to note that the '%s' format string does not exist on all OSes, so this code is not portable. If you want to check whether it's supported you can check `man strftime` on Unix-like systems.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I was not aware of this. You are welcome to edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: It should be mentioned that this drops the fractional seconds part (microseconds or whatever).

Comment: WARNING: This applies localized timezones! You will get different strftime behavior for identical datetime objects depending on the machine time

Comment: Moreover this **ignores timezone information** and assumes that datetime is in local timezone **even for offset-aware datetime**, with tzinfo set. Well, at least in Python 2.7.

Comment: javascript timestamp = python timestamp * 1000

Comment: Even though everyone else dislikes this answer, this was the only one I could get to *properly* set the timezone on my linux box. everything else seemed to be offset by some amount.

Comment: d = datetime.date(2011,1,1) to avoid "SyntaxError: invalid token"

Comment: @Hari Nice catch! Must be something new in Python. Answer updated.

Answer (score 44):

- **Assumption 1:** You're attempting to convert a date to a timestamp, however since a date covers a 24 hour period, there isn't a single timestamp that represents that date. I'll assume that you want to represent the timestamp of that date at midnight (00:00:00.000).
- **Assumption 2:** The date you present is not associated with a particular time zone, however you want to determine the offset from a particular time zone (UTC). Without knowing the time zone the date is in, it isn't possible to calculate a timestamp for a specific time zone. I'll assume that you want to treat the date as if it is in the local system time zone.

First, you can convert the date instance into a tuple representing the various time components using the `timetuple()` member:

```
dtt = d.timetuple() # time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
```

You can then convert that into a timestamp using `time.mktime`:

```
ts = time.mktime(dtt) # 1293868800.0
```

You can verify this method by testing it with the epoch time itself (1970-01-01), in which case the function should return the timezone offset for the local time zone on that date:

```
d = datetime.date(1970,1,1)
dtt = d.timetuple() # time.struct_time(tm_year=1970, tm_mon=1, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=1, tm_isdst=-1)
ts = time.mktime(dtt) # 28800.0
```

`28800.0` is 8 hours, which would be correct for the Pacific time zone (where I'm at).

Comment: I'm not sure why this has been downvoted. It addresses the OP's issue (the working code the OP labelled as "not working"). It doesn't answer my question (convert *UTC* datetime.datetime to timestamp), but still… upvoting.

Comment: Be careful. The assumption that "you want to treat the date as if it is in the *local system* timezone is the root of all issues with timezone in python.
Unless you're 100% sure of the localization of the machine that will run your script and especially if serving clients that can come from anywhere in the world, ALWAYS assume dates are in UTC, and do the conversion as early as possible. It will keep hairs on your head, trust me.

Answer (score 10):

I defined my own two functions

- utc_time2datetime(utc_time, tz=None)
- datetime2utc_time(datetime)

here:

```
import time
import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import calendar
import pytz


def utc_time2datetime(utc_time, tz=None):
    # convert utc time to utc datetime
    utc_datetime = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(utc_time)

    # add time zone to utc datetime
    if tz is None:
        tz_datetime = utc_datetime.astimezone(timezone('utc'))
    else:
        tz_datetime = utc_datetime.astimezone(tz)

    return tz_datetime


def datetime2utc_time(datetime):
    # add utc time zone if no time zone is set
    if datetime.tzinfo is None:
        datetime = datetime.replace(tzinfo=timezone('utc'))

    # convert to utc time zone from whatever time zone the datetime is set to
    utc_datetime = datetime.astimezone(timezone('utc')).replace(tzinfo=None)

    # create a time tuple from datetime
    utc_timetuple = utc_datetime.timetuple()

    # create a time element from the tuple an add microseconds
    utc_time = calendar.timegm(utc_timetuple) + datetime.microsecond / 1E6

    return utc_time
```

Comment: I browsed straight past your example.. Way to messy and complicated for such a simple thing.. Not pythonic at all.

Comment: @Mayhem: I cleaned it up a little and added comments. If you have a better and more generic solution to convert from time to datetime and back beeing able to set time zone - please let us know. Also let me know what a more *pythonic* example of my code should look like.

Comment: `datetime` is a poor choice of name for a  function parameter in `datetime2utc_time(datetime)`. It shadows the `datetime` import.

Answer (score 8):

follow the python2.7 document, you have to use calendar.timegm() instead of time.mktime()

```
>>> d = datetime.date(2011,01,01)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(calendar.timegm(d.timetuple()))
datetime.datetime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0)
```

Comment: how is it different from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279) if `d` is in UTC?

Answer (score 6):

A complete time-string contains:

- date
- time
- utcoffset *`[+HHMM or -HHMM]`*

For example:

`1970-01-01 06:00:00 +0500` **==** `1970-01-01 01:00:00 +0000` **==** `UNIX timestamp:3600`

```
$ python3
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from calendar import timegm
>>> tm = '1970-01-01 06:00:00 +0500'
>>> fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'
>>> timegm(datetime.strptime(tm, fmt).utctimetuple())
3600
```

**Note:**

> **`UNIX timestamp`** is a floating point number expressed in seconds since the epoch, in **UTC**.

---

**Edit:**

```
$ python3
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
>>> from calendar import timegm
>>> dt = datetime(1970, 1, 1, 6, 0)
>>> tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=5))
>>> timegm(dt.replace(tzinfo=tz).utctimetuple())
3600
```

Comment: @user908088 Convert `1970-01-01 06:00:00 +0500` to `3600` as you asked.

Comment: @user908088 There's no `timezone` in `python2`, you can do the calculation(`06:00:00` - `+0500` = `01:00:00`) manually.

Answer (score 3):

Using the [arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) package:

```
>>> import arrow
>>> arrow.get(2010, 12, 31).timestamp
1293753600
>>> time.gmtime(1293753600)
time.struct_time(tm_year=2010, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=31, 
    tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, 
    tm_wday=4, tm_yday=365, tm_isdst=0)
```

Comment: note: `arrow` uses `dateutil`  and `dateutil` has known [for many years](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/112) [bugs](https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/issues/57) related to timezone handling. Don't use it if you need correct results for timezones with a non-fixed UTC offset (it is ok to use it for UTC timezone but the stdlib handles UTC case ok too).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That bug only occurs *during* a transition, in an ambiguous time.

Comment: Looks like the bug was fixed on March 28th

Comment: Looks, like it is the best and cross-python solution. Just use **arrow**. Thanks;)

Comment: @MathieuLongtin dateutil may have [other issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17365806/4279)

Comment: I mean at the end of the day, this is garbage in garbage out.  The question leaves a lot of ambiguity. It totally depends on where it was recorded.  So *this* is an answer that is as correct as the question that was served.

A better answer might include the caveat that any conversion between timezones must come from a date that is aware of the timezone in which it was recorded.  The above does not do that.

Answer (score 2):

the question is a little confused.  timestamps are not UTC - they're a Unix thing.  the date might be UTC?  assuming it is, and if you're using Python 3.2+, [simple-date](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/simple-date) makes this trivial:

```
>>> SimpleDate(date(2011,1,1), tz='utc').timestamp
1293840000.0
```

if you actually have the year, month and day you don't need to create the `date`:

```
>>> SimpleDate(2011,1,1, tz='utc').timestamp
1293840000.0
```

and if the date is in some other timezone (this matters because we're assuming *midnight* without an associated time):

```
>>> SimpleDate(date(2011,1,1), tz='America/New_York').timestamp
1293858000.0
```

[the idea behind simple-date is to collect all python's date and time stuff in one consistent class, so you can do any conversion.  so, for example, it will also go the other way:

```
>>> SimpleDate(1293858000, tz='utc').date
datetime.date(2011, 1, 1)
```

]

Comment: `SimpleDate(date(2011,1,1), tz='America/New_York')` raises `NoTimezone`, while `pytz.timezone('America/New_York')` doesn't raise any exceptions (`simple-date==0.4.8`, `pytz==2014.7`).

Comment: I get an error on `pip install simple-date`, looks like it is python3/pip3 only.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me, pass through a function.

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime, timedelta 
import datetime


def utc_converter(dt):
    dt = datetime.datetime.now(timezone.utc)
    utc_time = dt.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
    utc_timestamp = utc_time.timestamp()
    return utc_timestamp



# create start and end timestamps
_now = datetime.datetime.now()
str_start = str(utc_converter(_now))
_end = _now + timedelta(seconds=10)
str_end = str(utc_converter(_end))
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm impressed of the deep discussion.

my 2 cents:

```
from datetime import datetime
import time
```

the timestamp in utc is:

```
timestamp = \
    (datetime.utcnow() - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()
```

or,

```
timestamp = time.time()
```

if now results from datetime.now(), in the same DST

```
utcoffset = (datetime.now() - datetime.utcnow()).total_seconds()
timestamp = \
    (now - datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds() - utcoffset
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date into a UTC timestamp, it's best to specify explicitly the timezone before generating the timestamp:

```py
from datetime import date, datetime, time, timezone


def utc_date_to_timestamp(utc_date: date):
    dt = datetime.combine(utc_date, time(tzinfo=timezone.utc))
    return dt.timestamp()
```

Note that in the above snippet, if we were to omit the timezone specification, we would have a potential problem if the local timezone is different from GMT (which is aligned with UTC). Consider this example:

```py
my_date = date(2021, 1, 1)
wrong_timestamp = datetime.combine(my_date, time()).timestamp()
print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(wrong_timestamp))  # 2020-12-31 18:00:00
```

Note that the specific value printed will differ depending on the local machine running the snippet.